# xrmquery.update -> update crm date field

Tags: datetime, typescript, dynamics-crm, crm, xrmquery

I'm writing a custom typescript page for a scan module.
When a code is scanned a datetime field on a CRM record needs to be updated.

Here is my code:

```
XrmQuery.update(x => x.cgk_bonuses,
            this.bonusId(),
            { cgk_datescan: new Date() }) 
            .execute(id => { });
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong for updating a datetime field?
Update other fields works fine.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have found a bug in relation to updating *Date and Time* fields in CRM through XrmQuery.

I have created an issue for us to follow up on this: 
[XrmQuery: Debug sending dates to CRM](https://github.com/delegateas/XrmDefinitelyTyped/issues/29)

Answer (score 3):

This issue has now been fixed in version 2.3.7

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Delegate.XrmDefinitelyTyped/